# Set property label with annotations inside an entity

Tags: symfony

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.")
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max="255",
 *     minMessage="too short.",
 *     maxMessage="too long.",
 * )
 */
protected $name;
```

The form will show the `$name` field label as `name`. Is there a way to define here the field label with annotations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's done in the form layer — be it [a form type or a form builder using the `label` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#field-type-options) or a [Twig `form_*` function](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html).